# Numerical Functions Compatible with Regions Fail with MeshRegions and BoundaryMeshRegions

Tags: bugs, computational-geometry

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.2**

---

Given a `MeshRegion`:

```
region = DelaunayMesh[RandomReal[1, {50, 3}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can numerically `Integrate` over it easily:

```
NIntegrate[x^2 y^2 z^2, {x, y, z} ∈ region]
```

> 0.0169908561

We can also `Integrate` over its boundary:

```
NIntegrate[x^2 y^2 z^2, {x, y, z} ∈ RegionBoundary@region]
```

> 0.151404597

if you replace `DelaunayMesh` with `ConvexHullMesh`, which yields a `BoundaryMeshRegion`, the same process works fine.
This does not come as a surprise as the documentation for `NIntegrate` suggests that integrating over regions in this way is possible.

Now we turn our attention to `NArgMin`. We can mimic the built-in `RegionNearest` as follows:

```
dist[x_?VectorQ, y_?VectorQ] /; Length[x] == Length[y] := Sqrt @ Total[(x - y)^2]   

regN[region_, point_] := NArgMin[{dist[point, x], x ∈ region}, x]
```

We can use it as follows:

```
regN[Disk[], {2, 3}]
```

> {0.55470039, 0.832050166}

```
regN[Sphere[], {2, 3, 4}]
```

> {0.371392166, 0.557086686, 0.742780105}

Note that `Disk[]` and `Sphere[]` are `Region`s. Let's try our `MeshRegion` from above:

```
regN[region, {2, 3, 4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So, it looks like while `NIntegrate` works fine with `MeshRegion` and `BoundaryMeshRegion` objects, other functions (`NArgMin`, `NArgMax`, `NMinValue`, `NMaxValue`, `NMinimize`, `NMaximize` etc.) that claim to work over regions fail for both. Is this an omission in documentation or implementation, or am I totally missing something here?

Comment: No, this is missing implementation. By all means mention it to the support. Concerning why, `Shphere[]`, `Disk[]`, etc work - those are symbolic (exact) regions and go to the symbolic regions solver, which is not the case for `MeshRegions`.

Comment: @user21. Thanks for confirming, I'll let them know about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been confirmed by *Wolfram Technology Group* as a bug.