# How to generate random points in a region?

Tags: random, distributions, regions

The *Mathematica* 10 documentation was updated for `FindInstance` adding support for regions.

In my use case, I'm trying to sample points in a set of disks:

```
region = DiscretizeRegion@RegionUnion@Table[Disk[RandomReal[4, {2}], RandomReal[1]], {10}]
FindInstance[{x, y} ∈ region, {x, y}, Reals, 2] // N
```

However the above code fails and generates the following error:

```
FindInstance::elemc: "Unable to resolve the domain or region membership condition {x,y}∈"
```

What's going wrong here?

Comment: Thanks @RunnyKine how can we escalate it to get a response?

Comment: It would be nice if more people reported it to them and linked to these questions here like I did.

Comment: `FindInstance` is not for generating random numbers ... If you already have the disks, it's trivial to find an instance of a point which lies within them.  Take the centre of any disk.  It doesn't even matter that you have several disks, you can just use a single one.  If you have any expectation that these numbers will be uncorrelated and uniformly distributed (within the disks) then do not use `FindInstance`.

Comment: @Szabolcs, while I agree with your comment above, that's not the problem here. The problem is that these numerical functions that have been advertised to work with regions don't work with `MeshRegion`s or `BoundaryMeshRegion`s e.g. see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57048/numerical-functions-compatible-with-regions-fail-with-meshregions-and-boundaryme).

Comment: @RunnyKine it has nothing to do with `MeshRegion`, try it and see (remove `DiscretizeRegion`). Its weird, and I'm reporting it.

Comment: In my own opinion, it is strange that the `region` satisfies `RegionQ` function but cannot be used just as a "normal" region in other function or structure(ie. `Reduce`, `FindInstance`, etc). I think it is a little bug. In the highly coherent system like Mathematica, it should not let this problem happen. And the way fixing this little problem seems pretty easy.

Comment: @Eric If the "way fixing this little problem seems pretty easy" - why don't you fix it and show us your result ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't clearly say. I mean the way solving this bug in kernel is easy for WRI. And I think the whole topic is absolutely been answered by you(for sampling plenty of points of the `region`) and @Junho Lee(for giving the solution to work `FindInstance` with `region`).

Comment: Some of the answers here should point the way for WRI to include this functionality in *Mma* in the future.

Comment: @MichaelE2 your wish has been granted for Version 10.2! http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint.html

Answer (score 65, accepted):

There are already good answers, but I'm going to improve the performance, generalize to any region in any dimensions and make the function more convenient. The main idea is to use `DirichletDistribution` (the uniform distribution on a simplex, e.g. triangle or tetrahedron). This idea was implemented by PlatoManiac and me in the related question [obtaining random element of a set given by multiple inequalities](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32501/4678) (there is also Metropolis algorithm, but it is not suitable here).

The code is relatively short:

```
RegionDistribution /: 
 Random`DistributionVector[RegionDistribution[reg_MeshRegion], n_Integer, prec_?Positive] :=
  Module[{d = RegionDimension@reg, cells, measures, s, m},
   cells = Developer`ToPackedArray@MeshPrimitives[reg, d][[All, 1]];
   s = RandomVariate[DirichletDistribution@ConstantArray[1, d + 1], n];
   measures = PropertyValue[{reg, d}, MeshCellMeasure];
   m = RandomVariate[#, n] &@EmpiricalDistribution[measures -> Range@Length@cells];
   #[[All, 1]] (1 - Total[s, {2}]) + Total[#[[All, 2 ;;]] s, {2}] &@
   cells[[m]]]
```

### Examples

#### Random disks (2D in 2D)

```
SeedRandom[0];
region = DiscretizeRegion@RegionUnion@Table[Disk[RandomReal[4, {2}], RandomReal[1]], {10}];
pts = RandomVariate[RegionDistribution[region], 10000]; // AbsoluteTiming
ListPlot[pts, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

> {0.004473, Null}

[image]

Precise test

```
pts = RandomVariate[RegionDistribution[region], 200000000]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {85.835022, Null}

```
Histogram3D[pts, 50, "PDF", BoxRatios -> {Automatic, Automatic, 1.5}]
```

[image]

It is fast for $2\cdot10^8$ points and the distribution is really flat!

#### Intervals (1D in 1D)

```
region = DiscretizeRegion[Interval[{0, 1}, {2, 4}]];
pts = RandomVariate[RegionDistribution[region], 100000]; // AbsoluteTiming
Histogram[Flatten@pts]
```

> {0.062430, Null}

[image]

#### Random circles (1D in 2D)

```
region = DiscretizeRegion@RegionUnion[Circle /@ RandomReal[10, {100, 2}]];
pts = RandomVariate[RegionDistribution[region], 10000]; // AbsoluteTiming
ListPlot[pts, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

> {0.006216, Null}

[image]

#### Balls (3D in 3D)

```
region = DiscretizeRegion@RegionUnion[Ball[{0, 0, 0}], Ball[{1.5, 0, 0}], Ball[{3, 0, 0}]];
pts = RandomVariate[RegionDistribution[region], 10000]; // AbsoluteTiming
ListPointPlot3D[pts, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

> {0.082202, Null}

[image]

#### Surface cow disctribution (2D in 3D)

```
region = DiscretizeGraphics@ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Cow"}];
pts = RandomVariate[RegionDistribution[region], 2000]; // AbsoluteTiming
ListPointPlot3D[pts, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

> {0.026357, Null}

[image]

#### Line in space (1D in 3D)

```
region = DiscretizeGraphics@ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[2 t], Cos[3 t], Cos[5 t]}, {t, 0, 2 π}];
pts = RandomVariate[RegionDistribution[region], 1000]; // AbsoluteTiming
ListPointPlot3D[pts, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

> {0.005056, Null}

[image]

Comment: Very nice (+1).

Comment: @ybeltukov Very nice answer. Could you just explain briefly why you use `DirichletDistribution`?

Comment: @s.s.o It is the uniform distribution on a simplex (e.g. triangle, tetrahedron).

Comment: Ah, I should have known my `randomBarycentric` function was (the special case of) a well-known probability distribution.

Comment: I love the cow distribution, +1.

Comment: It seems the first example does not work (anymore?) this does: `region = DiscretizeRegion@(RegionUnion @@ 
     Table[Disk[RandomReal[4, {2}], RandomReal[1]], {10}]);` Otherwise amazing program!

Comment: Similarly the second example should read (?) `region = DiscretizeRegion@(RegionUnion @@ (Circle /@ 
       RandomReal[10, {100, 2}]));`

Answer (score 28):

It would be nice if `UniformDistribution` worked on arbitrary regions, then we could simply do `RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[region]]`. Someone at Wolfram should get on that.

In the meantime, it seems we have to write our own sampling routines. [@m_goldberg's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57950/484) is very nice (vote it up!) and uses rejection sampling, which works for arbitrary regions. However it will become slow if the measure of the region is small compared to that of its bounding box, for example if the disks are small and far apart. On the other hand, since you have a `MeshRegion`, it is actually possible to generate uniformly distributed samples without any rejection. We will pick a mesh cell randomly with probability proportional to its measure, then pick a point uniformly within that cell.

Sorry, I haven't bothered to wrap the code up into a neat module.

```
SeedRandom[0];
region = DiscretizeRegion@RegionUnion@Table[Disk[RandomReal[4, {2}], RandomReal[1]], {10}]
```

[image]

```
d = RegionDimension[region];
coords = MeshCoordinates[region];
cells = MeshCells[region, d];
cellMeasures = PropertyValue[{region, d}, MeshCellMeasure];

randomCell[] := RandomChoice[cellMeasures -> cells]
randomBarycentric[] := Differences@Flatten@{0, Sort@RandomReal[1, d], 1}
randomRegionPoint[] := randomBarycentric[].coords[[First@randomCell[]]]

ListPlot[Table[randomRegionPoint[], {10000}], AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: This is very nice upgrade version of goldberg's answer

Comment: You can collect the already available `cellMeasures` like this: `PropertyValue[{region, 2}, MeshCellMeasure]`

Comment: @RunnyKine: Thanks, added!

Comment: @RahulNarain very nice...learned a lot...+1

Answer (score 28):

Good news! Version 10.2 of *Mathematica* has this built-in with the function [`RandomPoint[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint.html). From the documentation:

> - `RandomPoint` can generate random points for any `RegionQ` region that is    also `ConstantRegionQ`.
> - `RandomPoint` will generate points uniformly in the region `reg`.

The first example given is a simple disk, but there are a whole host of neat applications given in the documentation!

```
pts = RandomPoint[Disk[], 5000];
Graphics[{PointSize[Tiny], Point[pts]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 17):

Here is a work-around that will let you extract as many randoms points from a region as you wish.

```
SeedRandom[0]; 
region = 
  DiscretizeRegion @ RegionUnion@Table[Disk[RandomReal[4, {2}], RandomReal[1]], {10}]
```

[image: region]

```
randomFromRegion[region_, trials_] :=
  Module[{bounds, randPts},
    bounds = RegionBounds@region;
    randPts = 
      Transpose @ {RandomReal[bounds[[1]], trials], RandomReal[bounds[[2]], trials]};
    Select[randPts, RegionMember[region]]]
```

Let's see what we get from 5000 trials.

```
pts = randomFromRegion[region, 5000];
Length @ pts
```

> ```
> 2550
> ```

We extracted 2550 points that lie within the region. Here is how they are distributed.

```
Graphics @ Point @ pts
```

[image: points]

Comment: `RegionBounds` make rectangle region from circle. From the beginning, You ought to have made rectangle region.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your objection.

Comment: @JunhoLee. If you were referring to my assertion concerning approximating area, I agree it was erroneous and have removed it.

Answer (score 12):

In version 10.1 the undocumented function `` Random`RandomPointVector `` is useful:

```
region = DiscretizeRegion@RegionUnion@
 Table[Disk[RandomReal[4, {2}], RandomReal[1]], {10}];

Graphics@Point@
  Random`RandomPointVector[region, 1000, Automatic, Automatic]
```

[image]

The two `Automatic` arguments appear to be working precision and a method option - other allowed values are "Mesh" and "Rejection"

Comment: I think this may have developed into 10.2's `RandomPoint[]`

Answer (score 9):

```
SeedRandom[0];

region = RegionUnion @ Table[Disk[RandomReal[4, {2}], RandomReal[1]], {10}];

DiscretizeRegion @ region
```

[image]

```
points = RandomReal[{-1, 5}, {10000, 2}];

circles = List @@ (region /. Disk -> Circle);

Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[2],
  Transpose[{RegionMember[region, points] /.
     {False -> White, True -> Gray}, Point /@ points}], circles}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but (*region = RegionUnion@
   Table[Disk[RandomReal[{0, 100}, {2}], RandomReal[1]], {10000}];
RegionMember[region, RandomReal[{0, 100}, {100000, 2}]]*) crashes the kernel

Comment: @user5601 Your question is "How to generate random points in a region". It's not about `FindInstance` (see several comments), and it's not about the endless possibilities of "crashing the kernel". I answered your question using your own definition of `region`.

Comment: Right! I should have specified that I need many points!

Comment: region = RegionUnion @ Table[Disk[RandomReal[4, {2}], DiscretizeRegion is very slow, so if the number of disks exceeds 10000 then it freezes...

Comment: @eldo how to find the boudary nodes for these collocation points?

Answer (score 5):

`FindInstance` have to apply to a expression like an equation or an inequality. `DiscretizeRegion` does not make an inequality. You should apply like the following example.

```
region = RegionUnion@Table[Disk[RandomReal[4, 2], RandomReal[1]],
    {10}
    ];
DiscretizeRegion[region]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

```
RegionQ[region]
```

> True

```
FindInstance[RegionMember[region, {x, y}], {x, y}, Reals, 2] // N
```

> {{x -> 2.4597, y -> 4.09129}, {x -> 1.31552, y -> 2.00384}}

Comment: But `DiscretizeRegion` is a region. Because `RegionQ[]` returns `True`

Comment: Seems like it is too slow: (*region = RegionUnion@
   Table[Disk[RandomReal[{0, 100}, {2}], RandomReal[1]], {10000}];
FindInstance[RegionMember[region, {x, y}], {x, y}, Reals, 2] // N*)

Comment: @user5601 Please check technique applying method of `FindInstance`. I might guess you find the solution like this posting example.

Comment: @RunnyKine you right. `DiscretizeRegion` is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities.

Comment: @user5601 `RegionMember[region, {x, y}]` make inequalities. too slow is natural..

Comment: It seems ok not to `RegionUnion` too many disks.
    `\[ScriptCapitalR] = RegionUnion[Disk[{0, 0}, 2], Disk[{3, 0}, 2]];
    Reduce[{x, y} \[Element] \[ScriptCapitalR], {x, y}, Reals]  (*FindInstance also work well.*)`

Answer (score 3):

you can look at this question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52322/how-to-find-all-data-points-within-closed-curve)

This method also may work fine:

```
p1 = {x, y} /. FindInstance[x^2 + y^2 < 1, {x, y}, Reals, 1000];
p2 = {y, x} /. FindInstance[x^2 + y^2 < 1, {x, y}, Reals, 1000];
point = RandomChoice[Join[p1, p2], 1000];
Graphics[{Circle[], {Red, Point[point]}}]
```

Comment: `FindInstance` is not a random number generator.  There's no guarantee that it will give you uncorrelated random numbers with a uniform distribution.  What the OP is asking for a misuse of `FindInstance` that is going to lead to wrong results.

Comment: I know FindInstance is not a random number generator but I think they will be uniformly distributed even if the pointes are correlated. then I used RandomChoice to get random pointes. I don't know if this way is correct or not.