# Sampling Points Between Two Functions and Plotting Sample Points? (I have partial code)

Tags: plotting, code-review, sampling

I want to sample random points between $Cos(x)$ and $Sin(x)$ on $0 \le x\le \frac \pi4$[image]

I was able to do graph the function here in Mathematica. I would like to count, and then plot points between those two functions. I have tried the following, however, with no luck.

```
    counter[n_] := (hitsCount = 0; hitsPoints = {}; 
    Do[{x, y} = {RandomReal[{0, Pi/4}], RandomReal[{0, 1}]}; 
    If[Sin[x] <= y <= Cos[x], 
    hitsCount = hitsCount + 1; 
    hits = AppendTo[hitsPoints, {x, y}]], {i, 1, n}];)
    counter[10000]
    ListPlot[hitsPoints, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

However, instead of a large sample of points of that "pizza" looking shape between Cos(x) and Sin(x), I get a blank plot. Is there an issue with my code?

Comment: Apply http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57938/how-to-generate-random-points-in-a-region to `region = DiscretizeRegion@ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= Pi/4 && Sin[x] <= y <= Cos[x], {x, y}]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you very much for your help. Is there any way that I could get them to appear as individualized points on my screen instead of what appears to be tiles? Also, could I specify the number of points I need? I need 5000.

Comment: Aha! Yes, that's perfect. Would you mind sharing the syntax?

Comment: Jeez, I forgot I can close plotting questions as duplicate with a single vote.  If there are any issues, just let me know.

Comment: For what its worth, aside from some stylistic issues the code in the question works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Copying ybeltukov's `RegionDistribution` from [How to generate random points in a region?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57938/how-to-generate-random-points-in-a-region/61677#61677), we get:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= Pi/4 && Sin[x] <= y <= Cos[x], {x, y}];
region = DiscretizeRegion@reg;
pts = RandomVariate[RegionDistribution[region], 5000]; // AbsoluteTiming
ListPlot[pts, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
(*
  {0.003288, Null}
*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I get the following error: "The specification RegionDistribution
is not a random distribution recognized by the system"

Comment: Woops! I forgot a bracket when I copied somewhere. Don't know how I didn't catch the red error message.

Comment: @user12289 I'm glad it works for you.