# How do I draw random points from a region

Tags: random, regions

as the title,this problem have confused me a whole day.If I have a region,how can I yield a random member in this region.The region such as `Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}}]`or `(x>5&&x<9)||(x>11&&x<13)`

i want get a random member in the expected region.but the “FindInstance” will give me a same result in the scond time when i run it again.

my current solution is previously product some random member,then sift  that expected that.but the way will result in a long time,because it has yield  amounts of member that it don't meet the requestion.

Comment: @Simon Woods yeah,i had tried it today.I think i should revise my quetion,i want get a random member in the expected region.but the FindInstance will give me a same result in the scond time when i run it again.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18686)? An adaptation to *Mathematica* ought to be straightforward.

Comment: One thing you could do would be to use the optional fourth argument of `FindInstance` and find many points all at once. Then use these one by one.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. but if my region isn't a triangle?

Comment: You can triangulate any polygonal region, yes? Pick any of those triangles at random (use `RandomChoice[]` with the triangle areas as weights), then use the triangle point picking strategy.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. thanks for your directions.i have done it.

Comment: I don't have the latest version of *Mathematica* to confirm, but version 8 had nice goodies under the ```Graphics`Mesh` ``` context; `PolygonTriangulate[]` and `PolygonArea[]` are particularly relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the function `` Graphics`Mesh`GenerateUniformPointsInTriangle ``

```
gupiTriF = Graphics`Mesh`GenerateUniformPointsInTriangle;

Graphics[{Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}], White, Point[gupiTriF@500]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For an arbitrary triangle `tri`  you can use `FindGeometricTransform` to map the random points in the unit right triangle to points in `tri`:

```
fgt2DF = FindGeometricTransform[#, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}][[2]] &;

SeedRandom[1]
Row[Table[coords = RandomReal[{0, 5}, {3, 2}];
  Graphics[{Hue[RandomReal[]], Polygon@coords, 
      RGBColor[RandomReal[1, {3}]], Point[fgt2DF[coords]/@
         gupiTriF[RandomInteger[{100, 500}]]]}, 
      ImageSize -> 200], {5}]]
```

[image]

Similarly, in 3D, `` Graphics`Mesh`GenerateUniformPointsInTetrahedron `` does what its name says:

```
gupiTetF = Graphics`Mesh`GenerateUniformPointsInTetrahedron;
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], EdgeForm[], 
  Tetrahedron[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}], Red,
  Point[gupiTetF@1000]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For a random tetrahedron, you can use a geometric transformation similar to the 2D case:

```
fgt3DF = FindGeometricTransform[#, {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}][[2]]&;

SeedRandom[111]
Row[Table[coords = RandomReal[{5, 10}, {4, 3}];
  Graphics3D[{Hue[RandomReal[]], FaceForm[Opacity[.25]], 
    Tetrahedron@coords, RGBColor[RandomReal[1, {3}]],
    Point[fgt3DF[coords] /@ gupiTetF[RandomInteger[{100, 500}]]]}, 
   ImageSize -> 300, Boxed -> False], {3}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Following the advice of @Guess who it is. to use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18686/uniform-random-point-in-triangle

```
randPt[tri_Triangle] :=
  Module[{a, b, c,
    r1 = Sqrt[RandomReal[]], r2 = RandomReal[]},
   {a, b, c} = Identity @@ tri;
   (1 - r1)*a + r1*(1 - r2)*b + r1*r2*c];

triangle = Triangle[RandomReal[{0, 5}, {3, 2}]]
```

> Triangle[{{4.22625, 2.64524}, {0.95047, 2.79426}, {2.89314, 1.00168}}]

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{
   LightGray, triangle,
   Red, AbsolutePointSize[3],
   Point[Table[randPt[triangle], {n}]]},
  Frame -> True],
 {{n, 500}, 100, 10000, 100, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Would've used `Dot[]` myself: `{1 - r1, r1 (1 - r2), r1 r2}.{a, b, c}`.

Comment: …and with that, a definition pattern like `randPt[Triangle[pts_?MatrixQ]] := (* stuff *)` is useful as well.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. - Yes `Dot` would be better and faster.

Comment: I suggest using argument destructuring to improve `randPt`. That is, writing it as `randPt[Triangle[a_, b_, c_]] := Module[{r1 = Sqrt[RandomReal[]], r2 = RandomReal[]},  (1 - r1)*a + r1*(1 - r2)*b + r1*r2*c]`

Answer (score 2):

The general 2D case was discussed in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57938/3066), but a more robust version can be written

```
randomFromRegion2D[
    region_ /; RegionDimension[region] == 2, 
    trials_Integer /: trials > 0] :=
  Module[{bounds, randPts},
    bounds = RegionBounds @ region;
    randPts = 
      Transpose @ 
        {RandomReal[bounds[[1]], trials], RandomReal[bounds[[2]], trials]};
    Select[randPts, RegionMember[region]]]

tri = Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}}];
SeedRandom[1]; 
Graphics[{{GrayLevel[.75], tri}, Point @ randomFromRegion2D[tri, 1000]}]
```

[image: triangle]

However, the OP also asked about 1D regions such a one characterized by

```
(x > 5 && x < 9) || (x > 11 && x < 13)
```

I would like to discuss how handle such regions, which must be dealt with a little differently than 2D regions because the functions supporting regions in *Mathematica* insist that points in 1D regions be represented by a list containing a single numeric object. Thus, the 1D origin is `{0.}`.

The OP's 1D specification can be made into a *Mathematica* region by taking the union of two `Interval` objects.

```
rx = RegionUnion[Interval[{5, 9}], Interval[{11, 13}]]]

randomFromRegion1D[
    region_ /; RegionDimension[region] == 1, 
    trials_Integer /: trials > 0] :=
  Module[{bounds, randPts},
    bounds = RegionBounds @ region;
    randPts = RandomReal[bounds[[1]], {trials, 1}];
    Select[randPts, RegionMember[region]] // Flatten]

SeedRandom[1]; 
NumberLinePlot[randomFromRegion1D[rx, 50],
  Prolog -> {GrayLevel[.75], AbsoluteThickness[10], 
    Line[Transpose @ {rx[[1, 1]], {0, 0}}], 
    Line[Transpose @ {rx[[2, 1]], {0, 0}}]}]
```

[image: intervals]