# Expected area of random triangle

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random, geometry

I want to check the following theorem by using Mathematica:

> $\textbf{Theorem} $. If three point $P,Q,R$ are picked independently at random in the triangle $ABC$, than expected value of the area of triangle $PQR$ is
>
> $S_{PQR}=\frac{1}{12}S_{ABC}$

I tried:

first I define triangle $ABC$ with area $S_{ABC}$

```
triangle = Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}}];

area = Area[triangle]
```

but I don't know how to define new random triangle (random three point) inside the $ABC$ triangle.

I want to do something like this

```
t1=Graphics[{Red,triangle}]
t2=Graphics[{Black, rundomtriangle}]
Show[t1,t2]
```

than

```
S1=Area[triangle]
S2=Area[randomtriangle]
```

$\frac{S1}{S2}$ is a random number.

than plot this random numbers

```
ListPlot[S1/S2, S1/S2, S1/S2,...}]
```

but.. how to define `randomtriangle` ?

Comment: (1) Pick random point in rectangle from 0 to 2 on x axis and 0 to 1 on y axis. (2) If it is inside ABC then keep it. (3) Else "fold" it along the appropriate upper edge to put it inside ABC. (4) Do this for three points and that gives your random triangle interior to ABC.

Comment: maybe `Triangle@RandomPoint[triangle,3]}`?

Comment: The analytical solution that the expected area is 1/12 is described [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleTrianglePicking.html).

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**
I did not know about `RandomPoint`! New in v10.2 So just use

```
triangle = Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}}];
randomtriangle = Triangle@RandomPoint[triangle, 3];
```

For the `ListPlot`:

```
areas = Area /@ Triangle /@ RandomPoint[triangle, {n, 3}];
ListPlot[Area[triangle]/area]
```

**Unchanged:**

For stuff like this (sampling from a region) the RegionDistribution function as defined in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57938/how-to-generate-random-points-in-a-region) can be very useful. Copying the function unchanged:

```
RegionDistribution /: 
 Random`DistributionVector[RegionDistribution[reg_MeshRegion], 
  n_Integer, prec_?Positive] := 
 Module[{d = RegionDimension@reg, cells, measures, s, m}, 
  cells = Developer`ToPackedArray@MeshPrimitives[reg, d][[All, 1]];
  s = RandomVariate[DirichletDistribution@ConstantArray[1, d + 1], 
    n];
  measures = PropertyValue[{reg, d}, MeshCellMeasure];
  m = RandomVariate[#, n] &@
    EmpiricalDistribution[measures -> Range@Length@cells];
  #[[All, 1]] (1 - Total[s, {2}]) + Total[#[[All, 2 ;;]] s, {2}] &@
   cells[[m]]]
```

Then we can use it as follows:

```
triangle = Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}}];

region = DiscretizeRegion@triangle;
pts = RandomVariate[RegionDistribution[region], 3];

randomtriangle = Triangle@pts;

t1 = Graphics[{
   {Red, triangle},
   {Black, randomtriangle}
 }]
```

[image]

Comment: Of course. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The brute force approach:

```
        p0 = RandomReal[ {-1, 1}, {3, 2}]
```

> {{-0.639468, -0.471533}, {-0.0621599, -0.952355}, 
>      {-0.253727, -0.133992}}

```
triangle = Triangle[p0];
a0 = Area[triangle];
p = Select[RandomReal[ {-1, 1}, {30000, 2}], 
   RegionMember[triangle, #] &];
Table[Area@Triangle[RandomSample[p, 3]]/a0, {1000}] // Mean
```

> 0.0826126 (* ~1/12 *)

I posted this mostly to point out a seemingly good approach that does not work:

```
p2 = {x, y} /. 
   FindInstance[ Element[ {x, y} , triangle], {x, y}, 1500];
Table[Check[Area@Triangle[RandomSample[p2, 3]]/a0, 0], {1000}] // Mean
```

> 0.151361

Why? Well the `FindInstance` distribution is not even close to uniform..

```
GraphicsRow[{Graphics[{Line[Append[p0, First@p0]], Point@p}], 
  Graphics[{Line[Append[p0, First@p0]], Point@p2}]}]
```

[image]

`FindInstance` give a lot of points exactly on the edges (So that many point triples are colinear, hence the need for `Check` )