# How to generate certain number of random points in a convex hull mesh?

Tags: random, computational-geometry, mesh

I am a newbie to *Mathematica*. I have some 2D point data, and I generated a `ConvexHullMesh` from it. Now, I want to generate a certain number of random points within the convex hull. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Have you seen [How to generate random points in a region?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61677/27951)

Answer (score 12):

A convex hull returned by `ConvexHullMesh` can be used directly as a region specification in [`RandomPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint.html).

Below I generate a few random 2D points to use to generate a convex hull, then use that hull as a region to generate five new points with `RandomPoint`. The original points are shown in Black; the new random ones in red.

```
originalPoints = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {7, 2}];
hull = ConvexHullMesh@originalPoints;
newpts = RandomPoint[hull, 5];

Show[
 hull,
 Graphics[{
   PointSize[0.01], Point@originalPoints,
   Red, PointSize[0.02], Point@newpts
 }]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]