# Get random solution for equation with $n$ parameters and infinite solutions?

Tags: equation-solving, random

I'm trying to get a random solution for an equation with **arbitrary number of parameters** which has infinite solutions. Note that the answer must be in `n` dimensions where `n` is the number of parameters of the function.

---

**My tries:**

- The function can be something like `x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1`, in this case, the solution is a sphere and every point that satisfies that equality is a valid solution. This creates a region that consists of valid solutions, so if we generate a random point in that region we have a valid answer for this problem. That can be done using [ybeltukov's answer's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61677/46537) `RegionDistribution`:

  ```
  implregion = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + t^2 == 1, {x, y, z, t}];
  region = DiscretizeRegion[implregion];
  pts = RandomVariate[RegionDistribution[region], 100]
  ```

  but this raises an error saying `DiscretizeRegion` only takes arguments with less than 4 dimensions.
- I tried using `NSolve` to get all the points:

  ```
  NSolve[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, {x,y,z}] (* I don't know what I was supposed to see here *)
  ```

  but this gives a warning message that says:

  ```
   Warning: NSolve::infsolns: "Infinite solution set has dimension at least 1.
    Returning intersection of solutions with (171802*x-113492*y-121484*z)/178835 == 1."
  ```

  then it outputs some complex valued solutions, which are not valid (in this context):

  ```
  {{x->0.252383 - 0.412144I, y->-1.17075 - 0.0795353I, z->-0.0214382 - 0.508549I},
   {x->0.252383 + 0.412144I, y->-1.17075 + 0.0795353I, z->-0.0214382 + 0.508549I}}
  ```

  As you can see, it gets those wanted infinite solutions, and it even selects a random solution, but it is always the same, and contains complex numbers when what I want is one random answer of that `solution set` which consists only of real values.
- I also tried with `Reduce` doing:

  ```
  Reduce[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1]
  ```

  The result is:

  ```
  (x == -Sqrt[1 - y^2 - z^2] || x == Sqrt[1 - y^2 - z^2])
  ```

  and generating some points doing something like

  ```
  Table[
      {RandomChoice[{-1,1}] Sqrt[1 - y^2 - z^2], y, z}/.
        {y-> RandomReal[{-1,1}],
         z-> RandomReal[{-1,1}]},
  {1000}]
  ```

  gives me incorrect answers because `x`, `y` and `z` are not calculated "at the same time".

**Edit:**

- Using `FindInstance` distributes non uniformly the points, I used

  ```
  FindInstance[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, y, z}, Reals, 1000]
  ```

  and the result was

  [image]
- And the last method distributes non uniformly too, doing

  ```
  Select[Table[{RandomChoice[{-1, 1}] Sqrt[1 - y^2 - z^2], y, z} /.
                   {y -> RandomReal[{-1, 1}], 
                    z -> RandomReal[{-1, 1}]},
         {1000}],
  Im@#[[1]] == 0 &]
  ```

  gives me

  [image]

  this is because the values are calculated depending on the $yz$ plane and in some places `x` changes faster than in another places.

Comment: Have you considered `FindInstance`?

Comment: The results of your last approach, using `Table`, certainly are correct.  What is your concern with them?

Comment: Would `RandomPoint` do what you're after?

Comment: @ChipHurst Yes!

Comment: Generating a uniform distribution even on the sphere is highly nontrivial, an ellipsoid is very hard, and you can forget about arbitrary hypersurfaces, so your question is much too general.

Answer (score 3):

[`FindInstance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html) works quickly  but seems to biased toward points that lie in the xy-plane.

```
SeedRandom[42]; 
With[{n = 10}, 
  (FindInstance[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, y, z}, Reals, n] // N)[[All, All, 2]]]
```

> ```
> {{0.790419, -0.108434, 0.602893}, {0.367265, 0.930116, 0.}, 
>  {-0.538922, -0.842356, 0.}, {-0.538922, 0.842356, 0.}, 
>  {0.55489, -0.831924, 0.}, {0.968064, 0.158416, -0.194311}, 
>  {-0.407186, -0.913345, 0.}, {0.978044, 0.0658436, 0.197724}, 
>  {0.946108, 0.323852, 0.}, {0.55489, 0.831924, 0.}}
> ```

So I recommend

```
SeedRandom[42];
With[{n = 10},
  Module[{y, z},
   z = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n];
   y = RandomReal[{-1 + #, 1 - #}] & /@ Abs[z];
   MapThread[{Sqrt[1 - #1^2 - #2^2], #1, #2} &, {y, z}]]]
```

> ```
> {{0.899547, -0.41092, -0.148189}, {0.972747, 0.0791143, -0.217954}, 
>  {0.903025, 0.301654, -0.305861}, {0.882229, 0.46164, -0.0925187}, 
>  {0.760152, 0.640032, 0.111927}, {0.701265, 0.574829, -0.421661}, 
>  {0.868464, 0.284055, -0.406304}, {0.714105, -0.38114, -0.587185}, 
>  {0.922918, 0.161119, -0.349661}, {0.321531, -0.0217459, 0.946649}}
> ```

Comment: It is also biased, two peaks seem to have more points than the other two; [check it out](http://i.imgur.com/TL8qGAd.png)

Answer (score 1):

Region functionality in M11.2+ can handle [`Ellipsoid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ellipsoid) objects. For example:

```
pts = RandomPoint[
    RegionBoundary @ Ellipsoid[{0,0,0,0},{1,2,3,4}],
    10
]
```

> {{0.702264, -0.506915, -1.00603, -2.29828}, {0.672747, 1.1246, 
>     0.948138, -1.44966}, {-0.543024, 
>     0.140708, -2.00356, -2.01652}, {0.652806, -1.37052, -0.93464, -0.339369}, 
>   {-0.38219, -0.873541, -2.1748, 1.48397}, {0.220089, -1.55027, 
>     1.56574, -1.11951}, {-0.38265, 0.746885, 2.49541, -0.596283}, {0.52443, 
>     1.36327, -1.48924, 0.471912}, {-0.212721, 1.43821, 1.50939, 
>     1.71813}, {0.649815, -0.909925, 0.557857, -2.31921}}

Check that they all lie on the [`Ellipsoid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ellipsoid):

```
Norm/@(pts.DiagonalMatrix[1/Range[4]])
```

> {1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}