# RandomPoint not evaluating on RegionQ and ConstantRegionQ regions

Tags: random, geometry

When attempting to recreate and generalise the MatLab code for [Random Vectors with Fixed Sum](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9700-random-vectors-with-fixed-sum) by first principles I came across a few issue with [`RandomPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint.html).

According to `RandomPoint`'s documentation it should evaluate on any region that is [`RegionQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionQ.html) and [`ConstantRegionQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConstantRegionQ.html).  However this is not always the case.

For `s = 1.2; n = 3;`

```
rng = RegionIntersection[
       Cuboid[ConstantArray[0, n]], 
       Hyperplane[ConstantArray[1, n], s/ConstantArray[n, n]]
      ];

Through@{RegionQ, ConstantRegionQ}@rng
```

> ```
> {True, True}
> ```

However,

```
RandomPoint[rng, 1]
```

returns unevaluated.

Also, for higher dimensions such as `n = 4;`

```
rng4 = RegionIntersection[
       Cuboid[ConstantArray[0, n]], 
       Hyperplane[ConstantArray[1, n], s/ConstantArray[n, n]]
      ];

Through@{RegionQ, ConstantRegionQ}@rng4
```

> ```
> {True, True}
> ```

but

```
RandomPoint[rng4, 1]
```

returning unevaluated.

The `n = 3` case can be solved by [`DiscretizeRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeRegion.html) on `rng` in `RandomPoint`.

```
SeedRandom[123];

RandomPoint[DiscretizeRegion@rng, 1]

Show[
 Region[rng, Boxed -> True, Axes -> True],
 Graphics3D[{
   Black,
   PointSize@Small,
   Point@RandomPoint[DiscretizeRegion@rng, 1000]
   }]
 ]
```

> ```
> {{0.716182,0.258674,0.225143}}
> ```
>
> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Unfortunately `DiscretizeRegion` does not work on higher dimensions.

<strike>I know that I can generate the vectors in higher dimensions with</strike>

```
s Standardize[RandomReal[1,n],0&,Total]
```

but the point is to demonstrate from first principles. 
  That actually doesn't work.

1. Is there a way to get the expected functionality out of `RandomPoint` for regions that are `RegionQ` and `ConstantRegionQ`?
2. Can anyone reproduce the issues above? Win 8.1 Mma 11.3.0

Comment: The algorithm used for `rgn4` would generate a random point in the bounded `Cuboid` and keep those that lie on the unbounded `Hyperplane`, which would never be expected to happen; so in fact, `RandomPoint` fails when the dimension of the unbounded region is less than the bounded one. It seems to be an undocumented restriction.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Is this not a limitation of `RegionIntersection` then since it is not producing a bounded region in this case? Should it not produce an $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ polygon in the `n=4` case as it does in the `n=3` case?  Perhaps too complicated so goes for `BooleanRegion`.

Comment: It's a limitation of `RandomPoint`, and the restriction applies to `rng`, too. Yes, the region represents a polyhedron in ${\bf R}^4$. But how would represent that in *M* except by a union of `Simplex[]` objects or an intersection of a bounded and unbounded region? If the region is a `MeshRegion` (which is a union of simplices), then a different algorithm is used, perhaps @ybeltukov's [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57938/how-to-generate-random-points-in-a-region), which predates `RandomPoint`. If you can triangulate `rng4` into simplices, then `RandomPoint` will work.