# How to generate random dots with given distances?

Tags: regions, random, distributions

I am interested in the following problem, and am curious if Mathematica could be used to solve it.

I start with a radius function $\rho:D\to \mathbf{R}_{\ge 0}$ on a region $D\subseteq \mathbf{R}^n$. Fix $r_2>r_1$ and a finite subset $S_0\subset D$ of points.

**Problem**: I am interested randomly in generating a fairly large set $S\supset S_0$ of dots $x_i$ in $D$ such that
$$|x_i-x_j|\ \not\in\ [\rho(x_i)r_1,\rho(x_i)r_2]$$
for all $i\ne j$.

There are [lots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57938/how-to-generate-random-points-in-a-region/61677) of example uses of Mathematica generating a random set of points, but I am not sure how to alter these solutions to include this condition on the distances between the points.

To be extremely precise for the sake of argument, take for instance $D=[0,1]^2\subseteq \mathbf{R}^2$ with $r_1=1$, $r_2=2$ and radius function $\rho(x,y)=x^2+xy+y^2.$

Comment: A specific example with $n=2$ or $n=3$ is essential to include.  What you've tried (even if you didn't get too far) with that example in *Mathematica* would also be helpful.

Comment: Shouldn't your density function integrate to 1 over $[0,1]^2$ ? `Integrate[x^2 + x y + y^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}] = 11/12`.

Comment: Apologies- it was a bad name, $\rho$ only appears in the radius condition rather than the distribution using which the points are sampled. I have edited my question to call $\rho$ a radius function instead.

Comment: So I'm a little slow:  if $\rho$ is not a density function, what it the distribution from which the points are sampled?

Comment: Apologies again- I left this deliberately ambiguous, but would be happy even with e.g. uniform distribution. I left it ambiguous because the obvious solution is to produce $x_1$ using the uniform distribution, then use the uniform distribution outside the disallowed region, and repeat. The resulting set will not be uniformly distributed, but I am not too concerned about that.

Comment: As for Mathematica, I had two ideas, but I am too bad at Mathematica to implement them. The first is to fiddle with the answer in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57938/how-to-generate-random-points-in-a-region?noredirect=1&lq=1 somehow. The second is to manually do what I mentioned in my above comment using RandomPoint and if loops, but I imagine that would be an extremely slow program.

Comment: Answer to this question probably depends a lot on whether you want to maximise the number of points or just find a valid solution. (A wiseguy could probably offer a single point as a valid solution, though.)

Comment: I am just interested in a valid solution with a lot of points.

Comment: While it's not computationally efficient, you could do "sample rejection". Generate points from the whole interval, then check them to see if they violate your constraint. If they do, throw them away, else keep them.

Answer (score 3):

This (I hope after discussion with OP), is closer to what is desired. This **does not** scale well (not >100 points). I just use euclidean norm but this could be changed.

I only post it in case it motivates others.

```
rand[n_, a_, b_] := Module[{r = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 2}], rg, cl},
  rg = RelationGraph[
    Not[a < EuclideanDistance[#1, #2] < b && 
       EuclideanDistance[#1, #2] != 0] &, r];
  cl = First@FindClique[rg];
  Graphics[{Red, Point[r], Black, PointSize[0.03], Point[#]} & /@ cl, 
   Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Frame -> True]]
```

The red points are the original points and the black over red points are those that comply with constraint.

Illustrating this:

```
Manipulate[
 With[{plot = rand[100, a, a + b]}, 
  Manipulate[
   Show[plot, 
    Graphics[{Circle[p, a], Circle[p, a + b]}]], {p, {0.5, 0.5}, 
    Locator, Appearance -> "+"}]], {a, {0.05, 0.1, 0.2}, 
  PopupMenu}, {b, {0.1, 0.2, 0.3}, PopupMenu}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a brute-force approach (which is essentially a poor copy of @ubpdqn 's answer):

```
SeedRandom[12345];

(* Set parameters *)
f[r_, {x_, y_}] := r (x^2 + x y + y^2)
r1 = 0.1;
r2 = 0.3;

(* Number of points to select *)
n = 50;

(* Array to store sequential plots *)
plt = ConstantArray[0, n];

(* Initial point *)
pts = {RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 2]};
noPts = {};
m = 100;  (* Fineness of grid showing area where no points can be selected *)
(* Create a list of points on a fine grid that can no longer be selected *)
Do[Do[status = True;
  If[f[r1, {i/m, j/m}] <= Norm[{i/m, j/m} - pts[[1]]] <= f[r2, {i/m, j/m}], status = False];
  If[status == False, noPts = Join[noPts, {{i/m, j/m}}]], {i, m}], {j, m}];
plt[[1]] = 
  ListPlot[{pts, noPts, pts}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Blue, PointSize[0.01]}, {Gray, PointSize[0.005]}, {Red, PointSize[0.02]}}, Frame -> True];

(* Selete points 2 through n *)
Do[good = False; (* Initial status of potential sample point *)
 While[! good,
  {x0, y0} = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 2];
  status = True;  (* 
  Assume status of potential sample point is true until proven otherwise *)
  (* Check on relationship with all other points *)
  Do[If[f[r1, {x0, y0}] <= Norm[{x0, y0} - pts[[j]]] <= 
     f[r2, {x0, y0}], status = False], {j, 1, h - 1}];
  If[status, good = True; pts = Join[pts, {{x0, y0}}]]];
 
 (* Highlight locations where the next point cannot occur *)
 noPts = {};
 m = 100;
 Do[Do[status = True;
   Do[If[f[r1, {i/m, j/m}] <= Norm[{i/m, j/m} - pts[[k]]] <= f[r2, {i/m, j/m}], status = False], 
   {k, h}];
   If[status == False, noPts = Join[noPts, {{i/m, j/m}}]], {i, m}], {j, m}];
 
 (* Create plot of currently sampled points and the area that can no longer be sampled *)
 plt[[h]] = ListPlot[{pts, noPts, {pts[[h]]}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Blue, PointSize[0.01]}, {Gray, PointSize[0.005]}, {Red, PointSize[0.02]}}, Frame -> True],
 
 {h, 2, n}]
```

[image: Sequential sampling of points]

The red dot represents the currently sampled point and the blue dots are all of the previously sampled points.  The smaller gray dots represent the area than can no longer be sampled due to the restrictions imposed.

Comment: like it…have some other thoughts but too busy right now to test…mine not efficient but got ‘ball rolling’ :)