# Generate a 2D random point outside a region

Tags: random

I can generate a 2D random number within a square region, say $\{x,y\} \in [p_i,p_f]$, using

```
rand = RandomReal[{pi, pf}, 2];
```

I now would like to get a random number in this region but outside the sphere centered around `a` and with radius `r` with `a+r<pf` and `a-r>pi`.

In this [thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57938/how-to-generate-random-points-in-a-region) various ways of generating random numbers inside a region are discussed. However, I couldn't figure out how to modify the responses to solve my problem.

Comment: Use `RandomPoint` with an appropriate region (look up `RegionDifference`). Obviously, the region you use must be of finite size. If this did not work, be specific about where you got stuck.

Comment: @Szabolcs I can use `RandomPoint[Disk[], 1]` to generate a random number inside a Disk but how can I generate a number outside this Disk?

Comment: The outside of a disk is infinite. It makes no sense to ask for a random point within an infinite region, at least not with uniform distribution.

Comment: I already mentioned in my question that I would like to have my numbers to be inside a square! Anyway, I got an answer.

Comment: That is not at all clear from the phrasing.

Comment: @Szabolcs After double-reading my question can understand your point. I have modified the question for future readers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`RandomPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint) with [`RegionDifference`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDifference):

```
reg = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}], Disk[{0,0}, 1]];
pts = RandomPoint[reg, 10]
```

> {{-0.865556, -0.700941}, {0.913053, -0.737421}, {0.288003,
> 0.962705}, {0.772499,
> 0.856204}, {0.956926, -0.539727}, {0.29716, -0.99774}, {-0.544408,
> 0.968495}, {-0.78035, 0.657943}, {-0.600353,
> 0.836259}, {0.705759, -0.835619}}

Visualization:

```
Graphics[{LightBlue, DiscretizeRegion@reg, PointSize[Large], Red, Point[pts]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly faster method:

```
samplePointC = Compile[{},
  Module[{pt = {0., 0.}},
   While[
    pt = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2];
    pt.pt < 1];
   pt
   ]
  ]
```

Which gives the following timing:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 pts = Table[
    samplePointC[],
    {i, 1, 100000}];
 ]

>>> {0.0693943, Null}
```

The `RandomPoint` method gave ~ 0.986045 seconds. For those who are interested, I also tried reflecting points that are inside the diamond given by $|x|+|y|=1$ to reject about half as many points but this only caused a minor slow down. I used the following code before `pt.pt<1` to do this:

```
u = pt[[1]] + pt[[2]];
v = pt[[1]] - pt[[2]];
If[Abs[u] > Abs[v],
  If[Abs[u] < 1, u = Sign[u] 2 - u],
  If[Abs[v] < 1, v = Sign[v] 2 - v]
  ];
pt[[1]] = 1/2 (u + v);
pt[[2]] = 1/2 (u - v);
```

Comment: The `None` isn't really needed. `While[pt = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2]; pt . pt < 1]` will work.

Comment: @J.M. I updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

Here is a brute-force rejection method.  The speed depends mainly on the desired sample size and somewhat on the relative size of the circle within the square.

```
(* Set parameters *)
pi = 1;
pf = 4;
r = 0.66;
x0 = (pf + pi)/2 + r;
y0 = (pf + pi)/2 - r;

(* Relative area outside of circle *)
p = 1 - π (r/(pf - pi))^2;

(* Desired sample size *)
m = 100000;

(* Minimum sample size needed to be relatively certain to have at least m observations outside of the circle *)
n = (18 + m - 18 p)/p + 20 Sqrt[(9 + m - 18 p - m p + 9 p^2)/p^2] // Round;

(* Generate random sample excluding area in circle *)
SeedRandom[12345];
AbsoluteTiming[xy = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{{pi, pf}, {pi, pf}}], n];
  xy = Select[xy, (#[[1]] - x0)^2 + (#[[2]] - y0)^2 > r^2 &][[1 ;; m]];]
(* {0.394952, Null} *)

ListPlot[xy, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{pi, pf}, {pi, pf}}]
```

[image: Uniform random sample excluding area in circle]

Comment: (+1)This is a nice solution. Thanks for sharing.