# Problem on geometric probability

Tags: probability-or-statistics

This is a problem from the recent 18th Kolmogorov competition on probability theory and statistics 2023.
A random point `P` is chosen in an equilateral triangle. What is the probability
that the distance from `P` to the center of the triangle is less than or equal to the distance between
`P` and the boundary of the triangle?
I am aware of

```
tr = Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}}];
RandomPoint[tr]
```

I have got a problem to write down `P` as a random vector in WL. I'd like to see an answer in terms of [`Probability`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Probability.html?q=Probability).

Comment: As noted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61677), `DirichletDistribution[]` is the appropriate distribution for sampling uniformly within a simplex (in your particular case, an equilateral triangle). You can use this as a starting point.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how it may be useful. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @J.M.'slackofA.I.: See [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EquilateralTriangle.html#:~:text=An%20equilateral%20triangle%20is%20a,but%20all%20three%20sides%20equal.) concerning the terminology. Of course, I respect you as a moderator.

Comment: "Equilateral" is more conventional than "regular" for triangles with English speakers, so the terminological change clarifies it for more people.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As I noted in my comment, `DirichletDistribution[]` is the right distribution to use for uniformly sampling within a simplex. In particular, this generates barycentric coordinates for the triangle, so taking an appropriate linear combination of the vertices yields a point within the triangle.

The other answers have already shown where the parabolic arcs come from, so I'll skip ahead and present how to use `Probability[]`. (Note how I use a triangle centered at the origin to keep things simple):

```
tri = CirclePoints[{1, 0}, 3];
parabolas = Assuming[{x, y} ∈ Reals, 
    Simplify[RegionDistance[InfiniteLine[#], {x, y}]^2 - (x^2 + y^2) & /@ 
             Partition[tri, 2, 1, 1]]];

Probability[Block[{x, y},
        {x, y} = {x1, x2, 1 - x1 - x2} . tri;
        And @@ Thread[parabolas >= 0]] // Evaluate,
        {x1, x2} \[Distributed] DirichletDistribution[{1, 1, 1}]]
   5/27
```

(N.B. to visualize the region of interest as in Syed's and cvgmt's answers, evaluate `RegionPlot[And @@ Thread[parabolas > 0] // Evaluate, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]`.)

Comment: A good code is a commented code. However, I accept your answer. My trial was `TransformedDistribution[
 1/Area[Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}}]]*
  Boole[{x, y} \[Element] 
    Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}}]]*ud, 
 ud \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]]`.

Answer (score 9):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
r1 = Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}}];
r2 = Circle[{x, y}, EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, RegionCentroid@r1]]
cond = RegionWithin[r1, r2];

RegionPlot[cond, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}
 , Epilog -> {Red, Opacity[0.1], r1
   , Opacity[1], Point@RegionCentroid@r1}
 ]
```

[image]

```
r3 = ImplicitRegion[cond, {x, y}];
RegionMeasure[r3]/RegionMeasure[r1]
```

> 5/27

Comment: Thank you. This is done by hand with help of Mathematica. I'll be waiting for an answer which uses random variables and `Probability`. Of course, I think about it too.

Answer (score 7):

We directly translate  `the distance from P to the center of the triangle is less than or equal to the distance between P and the boundary of the triangle` to Mathematica code.

```
triangle = RegularPolygon[3];
reg = ImplicitRegion[
  EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, RegionCentroid@triangle] <= 
   RegionDistance[RegionBoundary@triangle, {x, y}], {x, y}]
Area[reg]/Area[triangle]
```

> `5/27`.

```
Graphics[{LightGreen, triangle, Magenta, reg // DiscretizeRegion}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is done by hand with help of Mathematica. I'll be waiting for an answer which uses random variables and `Probability`. Of course, I think about it too.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the following meets your request for the use of `Probability`.  (This approach  is essentially shamelessly stealing from @yarchik 's answer.)

Consider dividing the triangle into 3 equal parts and focus on the lower triangle:

```
triangle = ListPlot[{{-1/2, 0}, {1/2, 0}, {0, Tan[π/3]/2}, {-1/2, 0}}, 
  Joined -> True, PlotRangeClipping -> False, AspectRatio -> Tan[π/3]/2, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1/2, 1/2}, {0, Tan[π/3]/2}}];
lowersubTriangle = ListPlot[{{-1/2, 0}, {1/2, 0}, {0, Tan[π/6]/2}, {-1/2, 0}}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red, Joined -> True];
Show[triangle, lowersubTriangle]
```

[image: Equilateral triangle and lower sub-triangle]

Now calculate the squares of the distances of a random point to the center of mass (the peak of the lower triangle) and the floor of the lower triangle.  We want to know the probability that `d2com < d2floor`.

```
(* Square of distance to center of mass*)
d2com = (x - 0)^2 + (y - Tan[π/6]/2)^2;

(* Square of distance to floor of triangle *)
d2floor = y^2;
```

We sample uniformly in a rectangle that surrounds the lower triangle and account for the fact that we're only interested in half of the area of that rectangle by restricting the points to the lower triangle:

```
restrictions = y < (x + 1/2) Tan[π/6] && y < (1/2 - x) Tan[π/6];
probability = 2 Probability[d2com < d2floor && restrictions, 
  {x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-1/2, 1/2}], 
   y \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, Tan[π/6]/2}]}]
(* 5/27 *)
```

Comment: Something to adjust: what are `d2com` and `d2floor`? Your code (as presented in your answer) produces `Boole[d2com < d2floor]`, not `5/27` to me.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I forgot to paste those in.  I'll fix it.

Comment: +1. Now it works. However,  `d2com` and `d2floor` are done by hand. Compare with `parabolas = Assuming[{x, y} ∈ Reals, 
    Simplify[RegionDistance[InfiniteLine[#], {x, y}]^2 - (x^2 + y^2) & /@ 
             Partition[tri, 2, 1, 1]]];` in the J.M.'s answer. My trial was `TransformedDistribution[  1/Area[Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}}]]*   Boole[{x, y} \[Element]      Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}}]]*ud,   ud \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]]`.

Comment: Equivalently: `Probability[x^2 + (y - Tan[π/6]/2)^2 < y^2 /. Thread[{x, y} -> {x1, x2, 1 - x1 - x2} . {{-1/2, 0}, {1/2, 0}, {0, Tan[π/6]/2}}], {x1, x2} \[Distributed] DirichletDistribution[{1, 1, 1}]]`

Answer (score 3):

Here a geometric solution

```
ver = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}};
tr = Triangle[ver];
rand = Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {0, 0}}]
cent = RegionCentroid[tr];

reg = ImplicitRegion[Norm[cent - {x, y}] <= RegionDistance[rand, {x, y}] &&Element[{x, y}, tr], {x, y}]
Show[{Graphics[rand], Region[reg]}]
```

[image]

Probability follows to

```
Area[reg]/Area[tr]
(*5/27*)
```

Comment: Thank you for your visualization.  This is done by hand with help of Mathematica. I'll be waiting for an answer which uses random variables and `Probability`.

Answer (score 2):

Let us place the center at $(0,b)$ with

```
b = 1/2 Tan[Pi/6]
```

The sub-triangle (by symmetry, it is indeed sufficient to consider a 1/6 of the original triangle) of interest is

```
Plot[{(x^2 + b^2)/(2 b), b (1 - 2 x)}, {x, 0, 1/2}]
```

[image]

The orange line is the line from the center to a triangle vertex. The blue line shows the curve of equal distances, solution of the equation
$$
y^2=x^2+(b-y)^2.
$$

The probability is the ratio of the two areas

```
s1 = Area[
  ImplicitRegion[0 <= y <= b (1 - 2 x) && 0 <= x <= 1/2, {x, y}]];
s2 = Area[
  ImplicitRegion[(x^2 + b^2)/(2 b) <= y <= b (1 - 2 x) && 0 <= x <= 1/2, {x, y}]]
s2/s1
(*5/27*)
```

Here, $s_1$ is the area of the triangle formed by the orange line and two axes. $s_2$ is the area of the part of the triangle above the blue parabola. If the distribution is uniform,  the ratio of areas is equal to the probability of interest.

Comment: Thank you. This is done by hand with help of Mathematica. I'll be waiting for an answer which uses random variables and Probability. Of course, I think about it too.

Comment: @user64494 Yes, you are right, other solutions are also quite geometric and maybe even more straightforward in translating words into calculations. If  a probabilistic solution is needed, you could perhaps ask a similar but more complicated question that does not have a geometric interpretation. But I do not have a concrete idea.