# Discretizing higher dimensional region (simplex)

Tags: simplex, discretizeregion

I want to create an evenly distributed set of $N$ points inside a d-dimensional simplex ($d>3$), i.e. I want to have $N$ vectors $\vec{a}=\{a_1,a_2,...,a_d\}$ such that $0\leq a_j \leq 1$ for all $1\leq j\leq d$, and $a_1+a_2+...+a_d= 1$.
For being specific, let's assume I want 10.000 points inside a 4-dimensional simplex.
How can I do this?

For dimensions $d\leq 3$ I found a great answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57938/how-to-generate-random-points-in-a-region).
In this low-dimensional case I also know of the package `` NDSolve\`FEM\` ``  from which I could use the function `ToElementMesh` to create a set of points inside the simplex. However, this also only seems to work for $d\leq 3$ and for $d>3$ it raises an error `-- Message text not found --`.

I could of course simply generate pseudo-random numbers using `RandomReal[]` which would satisfy $a_1+a_2+...+a_d= 1$, however, they would probably not be evenly distributed.

Any ideas how I could implement this? All suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: If you need random points, evenly distributed in the simplex, you can use `RandomPoint[Simplex[{{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}]]`.

Comment: Thanks, that's probably what I needed. Could you give this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Or do you need them equally spaced on a rectangular grid?

Comment: No, randomly distributed is totally fine. But out of curiosity, do you also have an idea for solving it on a rectangular grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`RandomPoint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint.html) on [`Simplex`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplex.html):

```
RandomPoint[Simplex[{{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}]]
(*  {0.391776, 0.0488213, 0.410239, 0.149163} *)

Total[%]
(* 1. *)
```